# Optimize WHERE clause in query

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT table2.serialcode,
       p.name,
       date,
       power,
       behind,
       direction,
       length,
       centerlongitude,
       centerlatitude,
       currentlongitude,
       currentlatitude
FROM table1 as table2
  JOIN pivots p ON p.serialcode = table2.serial
WHERE table2.serialcode = '49257' 
and date = (select max(a.date) from table1 a where a.serialcode ='49257');
```

It seems it is retrieving the select max subquery for each join. It takes a lot of time. Is there a way to optimize it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Please add the definition of the tables involved including any index defined and the execution plan (plain text please, no screenshots)

Comment: Why do you need subquery here? You can get maximum date, store it in a variable and use that variable as parameter as it is not changing for each row.

Comment: @Harsh: any decent optimizer will only run that sub-query once as it is not related to the outer query.

Comment: If `serialcode` is a number, then you should compare it to a number not a character literal (`49257` is a number `'49257'` is a string). Some DBMS might not use an index if the data types of the column and the compared value do not match

Answer (score 2):

Sub selects that end up being evaluated "per row of the main query" can cause tremendous performance problems once you try to scale to larger number of rows.

Sub selects can almost always be eliminated with a data model tweak.

Here's one approach: add a new `is_latest` to the table to track if it's the max value (and for ties, use other fields like created time stamp or the row ID). Set it to 1 if true, else 0.

Then you can add `where is_latest = 1` to your query and this will radically improve performance.

You can schedule the update to happen or add a trigger etc. if you need an automated way of keeping `is_latest` up to date.

Other approaches involve 2 tables - one where you keep only the latest record and another table where you keep the history.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @maxDate datetime;
select @maxDate = max(a.date) from table1 a where a.serialcode ='49257';


SELECT table2.serialcode,
           p.name,
           date,
           power,
           behind,
           direction,
           length,
           centerlongitude,
           centerlatitude,
           currentlongitude,
           currentlatitude
    FROM table1 as table2
      JOIN pivots p ON p.serialcode = table2.serial
    WHERE table2.serialcode = '49257' 
    and date =@maxDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize this query using indexes.  Here are somethat should help:  `table1(serialcode, serial, date)`, `table1(serialcode, date)`, and `pivots(serialcode)`.

Note:  I find it very strange that you have columns called `serial` and `serialcode` in the same table, and the join is on `serial`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned which DB you are using, I would answer if it was for Oracle.

You can use `WITH` clause to take out the subquery and make it perform just once.

```
WITH d AS (
  SELECT max(a.date) max_date from TABLE1 a WHERE a.serialcode ='49257'
)
SELECT table2.serialcode,
       p.name,
       date,
       power,
       behind,
       direction,
       length,
       centerlongitude,
       centerlatitude,
       currentlongitude,
       currentlatitude
FROM table1 as table2
  JOIN pivots p ON p.serialcode = table2.serial
  JOIN d on (table2.date = d.max_date)
WHERE table2.serialcode = '49257'
```

Please note that you haven't qualified `date` column, so I just assumed it belonged to `table1` and not `pivots`. You can change it. An advise on the same note - always qualify your columns by using `table.column` format.